# Apple II: What type of partition tables were used?

Tags: apple-ii, hard-disk, scsi, apple-dos

What type of partition table was used with ProDOS?

ProDOS (8-bit) version 1.2 was available in January 1983, one year before the Macintosh was released, so it is unclear to me if ProDOS 1.2 used the "Apple Partition Map", or something else.

The Wikipedia article for Apple Partition Map does not say anything about this:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Partition_Map

Comment: I don't have the info you're after, but I think you're off on your timeline — ProDOS *1.0* was available in 1983, but ProDOS 1.2 was released in 1986 (after the Mac), coincident with the IIgs.

Answer (score 10):

ProDOS provides a common device driver API for storage systems, but does not specify a partition table format. Rather, the SCSI (or other) HD interface card has firmware to map partitions to ProDOS volumes.

The Apple SCSI Card and Apple High-speed SCSI Card for the Apple ][+, //e, IIGS utilize the Apple Partition Map, just like with their Classic Macintosh SCSI HDs. Apple provided a tool "HDSCPARTITION" on the disk they shipped with the SCSI Cards to allow the user to setup partitions.